# Powerapps - Unable to get child gallery items

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas

I have parent & child blank vertical Gallery and for parent DataSource is `GroupBy(jsonData,"group_id","DATA")` here i have two groups. for child Gallery DataSource is `ThisItem.DATA`, in child gallery there are 5 text input fields, after clicking Submit button i am unable to get text input fields data from child Gallery.
I have tried below methods but ChildGal items count is always 0 only
`ForAll(ParentGal.AllItems,Notify(ThisItem.ChildGal.AllItemsCount,Success,3000))`,
`Notify(ChildGal.AllItemsCount,Success,3000))`

Comment: It doesn't seem possible to access control values more than one level deep within Galleries. Parent gallery can access child gallery control values, but not the parent of the parent gallery.

A common approach to similar scenarios is doing a `Patch` within the text input `OnChange` action which updates a secondary collection with the value. Then on Submit button, you loop through this secondary collection. If you want to explore this option then the child items will need to know which parent they belong to. Ie ThisItem in ChildGal should have an id or index of the parent.

Answer (score 0):

Currently we cannot access the AllItems property of a nested gallery from outside the outer gallery. One way to work around this limitation is to collect the data on the outer gallery (such as in a hidden label), and then this value can be accessed from outside.

For example, if I have this dataset:

```
ClearCollect( CityPopulations,
    { City: "London",    Country: "United Kingdom", Population: 8615000},
    { City: "Berlin",    Country: "Germany",        Population: 3562000},
    { City: "Madrid",    Country: "Spain",          Population: 3165000},
    { City: "Rome",      Country: "Italy",          Population: 2874000},
    { City: "Paris",     Country: "France",         Population: 2273000},
    { City: "Hamburg",   Country: "Germany",        Population: 1760000},
    { City: "Barcelona", Country: "Spain",          Population: 1602000},
    { City: "Munich",    Country: "Germany",        Population: 1494000},
    { City: "Milan",     Country: "Italy",          Population: 1344000}
)
```

And my (outer) gallery Items property is set to `GroupBy( CityPopulations, "Country", "Cities" )`, and I have the name and population of the cities in a nested gallery:

[image]

I can add a (hidden) label to the outer gallery with the following expression for its Text property:

```
Concat(Gallery2.AllItems, $"{City}${TextInput1.Text}", "|")
```

This will merge all properties of the nested gallery using the separators `|` (for each row) and `$` (for the properties I'm interested in).

From outside the galleries, I can then reference that property

```
Clear(myCollection);
ForAll(
    Gallery1.AllItems,
    ForAll(
        Split(ThisRecord.lblAllTextInputs.Text, "|"),
        With(
            { parts:Split(Value, "$") }, 
            Collect(
                myCollection,
                {
                    City: Index(parts, 1).Value,
                    NewPopulation: Value(Index(parts, 2).Value)
                }
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Hope this helps!